# Homestead not working as expected, ignoring config files

Tags: php, vagrant, homestead

One nicely day, my homestead stopped work normally.

So, my aliases not working any more, but my projects still working as before.

[image]

.bash_aliases

[image]

expected like this

[image]

Any ideas? I wont reinstall homestead, what you can recommend me to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `source ~/.bashrc` it's not permanent solution, but might fix issue temporary.

If that's the case look for issue in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` more about this => https://askubuntu.com/questions/161249/bashrc-not-executed-when-opening-new-terminal

Shell startup explained => https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13014

Comment: Thanks, this works. 

At least i can use aliases. Will think about permanent solution.